# Redmine: error in user profile view [mysql]

Tags: ruby, redmine

I've recently migrated from Trav 0.12 to Redmine 1.4.0.
After migrating data from Rrac to Redmine I get this error:

```
Processing UsersController#show (for xx.xxx.xx.xxx at 2012-04-16 12:45:36) [GET]


Parameters: {"id"=>"4", "action"=>"show", "controller"=>"users"}

NoMethodError (undefined method `<=>' for nil:NilClass):
  lib/redmine/activity/fetcher.rb:80:in `events'
  lib/redmine/activity/fetcher.rb:80:in `sort!'
  lib/redmine/activity/fetcher.rb:80:in `events'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:68:in `show'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `send'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
  thin (1.3.1) lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
  thin (1.3.1) bin/thin:6
  /usr/bin/thin:23:in `load'
  /usr/bin/thin:23

Rendering /mnt/storage/redmine/public/500.html (500 Internal Server Error)
```

I am new to ruby, can anyone help me?

**Note**: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096950/redmine-error-in-user-profile-view) is very similar problem described. In my case I use MySQL database instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patch to migrate_from_trac.rake

```
class ::Time
    class << self
      alias :real_at :at
      alias :real_now :now
      # Fixing import for trac 0.12
      def at(time)
        d = nil
        if time > 10000000000 then
            d = real_at(time / 1000000, time % 1000000)
        else
            d = real_at(time) 
        end
        d
      end
      def now
        real_now - @fake_diff.to_i
      end
      def fake(time)
        time = 0 if time.nil?
        @fake_diff = real_now - time
        res = yield
        @fake_diff = 0
       res
      end
    end
  end
```